# Extension of martingale representation theorem.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

It seems that the proof I am reading of the Martingale Representation Theorem,

"A square integrable RCLL martingale which is adapted to the augmented filtration of a Brownian Motion must be an Ito Integral wrt BM."

does not use any properties of Brownian Motion besides that the augmented filtration satisfies the usual conditions.

So for example, it should be true that the martingale representation theorem holds if $W$ is replaced by any strong markov process martingale.

Does anyone know of a result like this or do you know if some special property of Brownian motion is necessary for this result?

Comment: Sure that this is the statement of the martingale representation theorem? An Itô integral wrt Brownian motion has continuous sample paths whereas a RCLL martingale has not necessarily continuous sample paths, but might have jumps.

Comment: The continuous case is treated in Chapter 5.4 of Revuz/Yor.

Comment: @saz, I don't understand your comment. A RCLL mg adapted to the augmented filtration of BM will not have any jumps because it can be written as an Ito integral wrt BM by the MRT which I stated above.

Comment: @Seamus I guess, I misunderstood the statement. So the augmented filtration of BM is the completed canonical filtration, right?

Comment: Yes. It is the filtration generated by BM and the null sets of $F^W_{\infty}$. Note that this is right continuous since BM is strong markov.