# Martingale representation theorem with respect to different Brownian motion, than the one generating filtration?

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, martingales

Say I have a $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted stochastic process $Y$ with Itô-representation
$$Y_t=\int_0^t\alpha_sds+W_t$$
where both the Brownian motion and the integrable process $\alpha$ are $\{\sigma(Y_t)\}_{t}$-adapted. Moreover we know, that $\alpha$ is bounded by a constant $g\in \mathbb{R}$ and càdlàg, if that helps.
Now I have a square-integrable martingale $M$ with respect to $\{\sigma(Y_t)\}_{t}$ and I want to use martingale representation theorem to get something like this
$$M_t=M_0+\int_0^t\gamma_sdW_s.$$
Issue is I don't know if $M$ is $\{\sigma(W_t)\}_{t}$-adapted.
Now obviously I can use Girsanov to show that $Y$ is a Brownian motion with respect to some other measure $\widetilde{P}$ on the same probability space, but I don't know if this enough. To be precise this question is motivated by this paper https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/179372 Theorem 1 step 3.

EDIT: If [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929254/extension-of-martingale-representation-theorem) was actually true, it would answer my question affirmatively -or would it?